# How to show bilinearity

Tags: vector-spaces, bilinear-form, coxeter-groups

Given a Coxeter group $\varGamma =\langle \rho_0, \rho_1, \ldots, \rho_{n - 1}\rangle$ which at least satisfy the relation $(\rho_i\rho_j)^{p_{ij}}=1, \ \ 0\leq i, j \leq n - 1,$ where $p_{ii}=1$ and $2 \leq p_{ij}\leq \infty$ for all $i\neq j.$ On an n - dimensional real vector space V, with basis $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n - 1},$ we define a symmetric bilinear form $x\cdot y$ by setting $a_i \cdot a_j:=-2 \text{cos} \frac{\pi}{p_{ij}}, \ \ 0\leq i, j, \leq n - 1.$

How do I show bilinearity? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you have to show bilinearity - you are *told* that $x\cdot y$ is bilinear. Together with the $n^2$ values of $a_i \cdot a_j$ this defines the value of $x \cdot y$ for any $x$ and $y$. If you did not know the function was bilinear then you would know nothing about its value for general $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @gandalf61 I just want to verify how's it bilinear? Thanks

Comment: You aren't given enough information to *verify* that it is bilinear. You are just *told* it is bilinear. It's like this. Suppose you start a proof with "Let $p$ be a prime number ..." and someone asks "But how can I verify that $p$ is a prime number ?" ... they can't, they just have to take it as given that $p$ is a prime number and carry on from there.

Comment: If you are actually asking "what does bilinear mean ?", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form

Comment: @gandalf61 I was able to read about bilinear forms. I just don't know how to verify linearity in the above case.  Thanks